# can I use array.indexOf() with a function like .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, extendscript

I am using Extendscript which uses ECMAScript 3. So I am locked to many limitations. I am looking to find something similar to `Arr.find(func)` but available for ECMA3. Because I need a method searchs array of objects and find one object that has specific value in one of his properties. 
So I found `Arr.indexOf()` which is ECMA3 but not sure how to use it with a function since this method works with array of strings.

My question is is there a way to use .indexOf() with function (like `.find()`) to make it work with objects or any other solution?

Thanks,

Comment: You should post the code you are working with. It is unclear the exact structure that you need to search through.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `indexOf` Is ECMAScript 5.1; are you sure you can use it? Either way, the answer to your question is no, `indexOf` does not work with a function like `find`. You could possibly use `map` to convert the values of your array into something that would work with `indexOf` or use `filter` to filter your array down to just the values you're trying to find and then select the first of those

Comment: @ScottMarcus I based that on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Specifications

Comment: I believe you may be asking the wrong question. The MDN docs for both `Array.prototype.find()` and `Array.prototype.map()` (and others) have polypill code that you can include in your project and use just as if using ES5. Check these links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill

Comment: I don't see array.indexOf in the [ECMA 3 Spec](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf) (although string.indexOf is indeed there)

Comment: @Hamms My mistake. Comment deleted.

Comment: Thanks for helping me learn more about the older specs!

Comment: @HTN3D - have you considered polyfilling the `find()` method? Although that isn't the answer to your question, I do believe it is your solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for all answers. They were all useful to me. I used this function based on Scott Marcus suggestion:                            function findSelectedItem(list){
    for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
      if (list[i].selected === true){return i}
    }
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.indexOf()` won't help you here because it only searches arrays. You need to search objects inside the array, so you'll need to loop over the objects and attempt to find matches manually.

```js
var objArray = [
  {key1: "foo", key2: true, key3: 10 },
  {key1: "foo2", key2: false, key3: 100 },  
  {key1: "foo3", key2: true, key3: 101, key4: 101 }
];

function findKey(ary, findVal){
  // Loop over the array
  for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
  
    // Loop over objects keys
    for(var key in ary[i]){
      // Compare current key value against passed value to find
      if(ary[i][key] === findVal){
         console.log(findVal + " was found in object: " + i + ", key: " + key);
      }
    }      
  }
}

findKey(objArray, 101);
findKey(objArray, true);
```

Comment: This works as long as there isn't key4 with similar values, and you're finding objects by key1.

Comment: @mpartan The code does work under those circumstances as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is the Array-function that takes a function instead of value but gives index. I'm not familiar with ExtendScript, but there is a polyfill in that Mozilla Developer page that could be added. If there is map and find then findIndex could be there as well, but you could also combine map and indexOf with following way for a one liner.

```
var people = [{name: 'bob', age: 25}, {name: 'mary', age: 5}]
var index = people.map(p => p.name).indexOf('bob')
```

Comment: `.map()` and arrow functions are not part of ES 3. They were introduced with ES5, which the OP says he can't use.

Comment: I was unsure what is there and what isn't, as original poster refers to map in the title.

Comment: He said, "like" `.map()`. Meaning something that would provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all answers. They were all useful to me. I used this function based on Scott Marcus suggestion:

```
  function findItem(list){
    for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
      if (list[i].property === true){return i}
    }
  }
```